# Trunk port wont accept the Printer vlan

Tags: cisco, vlan, ios, trunk

I have three switches daisy-chained together and I have a printer vlan serviced with a print server off the core (1st) switch.  the middle switch trunk port will not accept the printer vlan.  I issue the following command   "switchport trunk allowed vlan all" which should add all vlans to the trunk.  HOwever, when I run the "show interface trunk" command the printer vlan is missing from the "Vlans in forwarding state and not prunned" list.  My switch is in vtp client mode and has a default route that is pingable. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  All switches are 3750s (12.52 IOS) except the core which is a 6509.

Comment: Does the printer vlan show up on the middle switch if you run "sh vlan"?

Comment: Post the output of: `sh vlan`, `sh vlan id $PRINTERVLAN` and `sh int $TRUNK switchport`.

Answer (score 1):

your switch is in vtp client mode, which means you cannot edit the vlan configuration on that switch. if you have setup vtp for the three switches then you'll want to make the changes on the vtp server switch. for such a small implementation, though, you should really put all three in vtp transparent mode (which will enable you to edit each switch configuration).